# react-hook-form Is it possible to validate onTouched and when last field is being filled?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have my mode set to `onTouched` to validate the fields on blur.  I also have my Submit form button to be disabled unless the form `isValid`.  The problem is that when the user is in the last field and typing AND it's valid, and all other fields are valid, the submit button is still disabled.  I would like it to be enabled at that point and the field to be validated.

Essentially, I would need to have the mode change to `all` or `onChange` once the user is in the last field, and all other fields a filled.

Edit: duplicate of [Enable/disable submit button with react-hook-form in onBlur mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66982034/enable-disable-submit-button-with-react-hook-form-in-onblur-mode)

Comment: `isValid` should just update when the fields become valid. There shouldn't be a need to `blur` or leave the input first. So there might be something else causing this issue. Where is your useForm defined, in the same component as the fields or somewhere higher up the chain?

Comment: Sharing some code might be helpful in this case

Comment: @Y.Gherbi it's in the same component.  `isInvalid` becomes true `onBlur` of the last field that is valid, but not when still focused inside the field even though it's valid.  So it appears `isValid` is working.

Comment: You are right! I looked up a project and posted how we did it. Let me know if this worked for you, they change quite a lot with their version upgrades

Comment: Could you accept an answer for this question if it helped you or if it didn't help you please comment with your problem or the fix if you have found one yourself. This way, we can help the next person with the same problem :) @avocodoo

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default behavior by passing options to your `useForm`.

Depending on your version, this should work. (I tested this on V6)

```js
const defaultValues = {
  name: '...'
}

const form = useForm({
  mode: 'onChange',
  reValidateMode: 'onChange',
  defaultValues,
});
const { isValid } = form.formState;
```

This will revalidate on `onChange` instead of on `onBlur`. You can also use this interchangeably with other events.

Comment: Could you accept this as an answer if it helped you or if it didn't help you please comment with your problem or the fix if you have found one yourself? This way, we can help the next person with the same problem :) @avocodoo