# How to submit with React Hook Form when having mode onBlur?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

This is not like what [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66982034/enable-disable-submit-button-with-react-hook-form-in-onblur-mode) is asking.

Basically, I have a form that I want to auto-submit whenever fields are changed. I.e. I do not want a submit button.

So, having this:

```
const {
  formState,
  handleSubmit
} = useForm<TSaveInputSchema>({
  mode: "onBlur",
  reValidateMode: "onChange",
  criteriaMode: "firstError",
  resolver: zodResolver(saveInputSchema),
});

const handleSave = useCallback<HandleSaveCallback>(
  (data) => {
    console.log("DATA SUBMIT", data);
  }
), []);
```

And HTML like this:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleSave)}>
  <input {...register("name")} />
</form>
```

does not call the `handleSave` function when the input field is blurred.

How can this be done, if possible? Or do I have to manually trigger the submit through other means (e.g. using `useEffect`)?

Answer (score 4):

Too much refactor for the day, the solution was dumb:

Replace

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleSave)}>
  <input {...register("name")} />
</form>
```

with

```
<input {...register("name", { onBlur:handleSubmit(handleSave) )} />
```